# Get Driver Install Dates

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am attempting to get a list of installed Drivers and the date they were installed via PowerShell. I have attempted the following:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, InstallDate
```

And the InstallDate property is blank for 100% of the items...

I also tried:

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All | Sort-Object Date
```

There is a date there, but it is not the install date. Probably the date the driver was compiled is my assumption.

As a misc note: MMC is not an alternative in this case. Long story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the InstallDate associated with the driver files and not with the driver objects from WMI.

Please find the code bellow for an example:

```
    # Initializing parameters (modify the Output folder by changing the $TargetDirectory define in the first line)
    $TargetDirectory = "C:\temp\DriversINFTest\"
    $hostname = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME
    # Get Third Party drivers used, that are not provided by Microsoft and presumably included in the OS
    $drivers = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver | where {$_.DriverProviderName -ne "Microsoft"}
    # Initialize the list of detected driver packages as an array
    $DriverFolders = @()
    foreach ($d in $drivers) {
        # We initialize the list of driver files for each driver
        $DriverFiles = @()
        # For each driver instance from WMI class Win32_PNPSignedDriver, we compose the related WMI object name from the other WMI driver class, Win32_PNPSignedDriverCIMDataFile
        $ModifiedDeviceID = $d.DeviceID -replace "\\", "\\"
        $Antecedent = "\\" + $hostname + "\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_PNPSignedDriver.DeviceID=""$ModifiedDeviceID"""
        # Get all related driver files for each driver listed in WMI class Win32_PNPSignedDriver
        $DriverFiles += Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriverCIMDataFile | where {$_.Antecedent -eq $Antecedent}
        if ($DriverFiles -ne $null) {
            foreach ($i in $DriverFiles) {
                # We elliminate double backslashes from the file paths
                $path = $i.Dependent.Split("=")[1] -replace '\\\\', '\'
                # We elliminate the trailing and ending quotes from the file paths
                $path2 = $path.Substring(1,$path.Length-2)
                # On the first pass, we only process the INF files as there is a very low chance of existing more than one driver package on the same machine, with the same INF file legth
                if ($path2.Split("\\")[$path2.Split("\\").Length-1].split(".")[1] -eq "inf") {
                    # We get the file attributes for each INF file
                    $CurrentDeviceID = $d.DeviceID
                    Write-Host "Current Device ID is $CurrentDeviceID"
                    $filedetails = $i.Dependent
                    Write-Host "Current inf file is $filedetails"
                    $where = $filedetails.split("=")[1]
                    $query = "select * from CIM_DataFile where Name=$where"
                    $InstallDate = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "ROOT\CIMV2" -Query $query
                    $ReadableDate = $InstallDate.ConvertToDateTime($InstallDate.InstallDate)
                    Write-Host "Installation date is:"
                    $ReadableDate
                    } # End of if ($path2.Split("\\")[$path2.Split("\\").Length-1].split(".")[1] -eq "inf")
                } # End of foreach ($i in $DriverFiles)
            } # End of if ($DriverFiles -ne $null)
        } # End of foreach ($d in $drivers)
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted the device name & driver date itself:
`$DeviceName = $d.DeviceName`
`Write-Host "Device: $DeviceName"`
`$DriverDate = $d.DriverDate`
`Write-Host "Driver Date: $DriverDate"`
I also put this at the top so you had a visual separator between drivers: `Write-Host "---"`
Mad kudos to @Narcis for sharing the good code!